# Pandas_UDF Concatenation loop with iloc

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pandas-groupby, user-defined-functions

I'm relatively new in Pandas and recently stuck with a User Defined Function.

My Dataset is like :

---

```
|header|planned|
|  a   |   1   |
|  a   |   2   |
|  a   |   3   |
|  a   |   4   |
|  a   |   5   |
|  b   |   1   |
|  b   |   2   |
|  b   |   3   |
|  b   |   4   |
|  b   |   5   |
```

---

I have to concatenate values in column `planned` by groups of two rows to obtain something like this :

---

```
|header|planned|p_cat|
|  a   |   1   | 1_2 | 
|  a   |   2   | 2_3 |
|  a   |   3   | 3_4 |
|  a   |   4   | 4_5 |
|  a   |   5   |     |
|  b   |   1   | 1_2 |
|  b   |   2   | 2_3 |
|  b   |   3   | 3_4 |
|  b   |   4   | 4_5 |
|  b   |   5   |     |
```

---

Numbers in column `planned` are not in this specific order but will always be integers.

My UDF:

---

```
schema = ds_adh.schema

    @pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def concat_operations(ds_op):

        s = ds_op['planned']

        for index in range(ds_op['planned'].count()-1):
        
            # clearly working only for the last index
            couple = str([s.iloc[index]]) + '_' + str([s.iloc[index+1]])

        ds_op_new = ds_op

        ds_op_new ['p_cat'] = couple

        return ds_op_new

ds_adh = ds_adh.orderBy("time")
ds_adh = ds_adh.groupBy("header").apply(concat_operations)
```

---

My problems :

- The concatenation itself doesn't work
- I don't know how to push concatenations in `couple` for all the iterations of the loop

I also tried with pandaSeries without any success.

Here is the error I get with this code :

---

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

---

Comment: is this a dummy problem or the actual one? based on that users can try and replicate using pyspark builtins, udf may not be required.

Comment: As my dataset contains 7 million rows, I've thought that UDF would be the solution for performance gain. I've spent hours on trying multiple syntaxes without success, indeed this error could be hiding major ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inbuilt window **`lead`** function with **`partitionBy`** on header and orderBy on planned column, As **`udf`** will decrease the performance.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
w=Window.partitionBy("header").orderBy("planned")
df.withColumn("p_cat", when(lead(col("planned"),1).over(w).isNull(),lit("")).otherwise(concat_ws("_",col("planned"),lead(col("planned"),1).over(w)))).show()
#+------+-------+-----+
#|header|planned|p_cat|
#+------+-------+-----+
#|     a|      1|  1_2|
#|     a|      2|  2_3|
#|     a|      3|  3_4|
#|     a|      4|  4_5|
#|     a|      5|     |
#|     b|      1|  1_2|
#|     b|      2|  2_3|
#|     b|      3|  3_4|
#|     b|      4|  4_5|
#|     b|      5|     |
#+------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Seems that I was wrong using udf this time (though it would increase performance as I have 7+ million rows in my Dataset). I'l try that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this is an actual problem , you can use pyspark builtins, something like below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
w = Window.partitionBy("header").orderBy("idx")

(df.withColumn("idx",F.monotonically_increasing_id())
   .withColumn("Lead",F.lead("planned").over(w))
   .withColumn("p_cat",F.when(F.col("Lead").isNull(),'')
   .otherwise(F.concat_ws("_","planned","Lead")))
   .orderBy("idx").drop("idx","Lead")).show()
```

---

```
+------+-------+-----+
|header|planned|p_cat|
+------+-------+-----+
|     a|      1|  1_2|
|     a|      2|  2_3|
|     a|      3|  3_4|
|     a|      4|  4_5|
|     a|      5|     |
|     b|      1|  1_2|
|     b|      2|  2_3|
|     b|      3|  3_4|
|     b|      4|  4_5|
|     b|      5|     |
+------+-------+-----+
```